# How to make NetBeans understand PHPDoc and PHPStorm Type hinting with 2 stars?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpstorm, type-hinting

Is there a way to make NetBeans understand PHPDoc (and old PHPStorm) format of Type hinting?

PhpStorm is using regular phpdoc blocks:

```
/** @var ClassName $object */
```

Netbeans/Eclipse/Zend style (supported by PhpStorm since 2.1)

```
/* @var $object ClassName */
```

Differences

1) Comment starts with `/*` rather than `/**` (thus it does not follow phpdoc convention).

2) And the arguments are swapped (PhpStorm accepts any order)

```
/* @var ClassName $object */
```

Comment: What do you mean by "(and old PHPStorm) format" ? PhpStorm supports all 4 variants simply because other IDEs/existing-at-that-time code used it, not because it has introduced it; and that's only affects inline `@var` comments -- all other stuff folows PHPDoc style (well, maybe `@param` as well -- not so sure).